# java script looping for dynamic data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to do looping in the given java script to dynamically fetch data from folder like song,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        Amplitude.init({
            "songs": [
                {
                    "name": "Living Proof",
                    "artist": "Gregory Alan Isakov",
                    "album": "The Weatherman",
                    "url": "HH.mp3",
                    "live": false,
                    "cover_art_url": "images/theweatherman.jpg"
                },

            ],
            "default_album_art": "images/no-cover-large.png",
            "callbacks": {
                "after_init": "album_change",
                "after_album_change": "album_change",
                "after_song_ended": "album_change"
            }
        });

        function album_change(){
            var activeSong = Amplitude.getActiveSongMetadata();

            $('.album-display').hide();
            $('.album-container').removeClass('active-album-container');

            switch( activeSong.album ){
                case 'The Weatherman':
                    $('.the-weatherman-display').show();
                    $('.the-weatherman').addClass('active-album-container');
                break;
                case 'Rooms For Adelaide':
                    $('.rooms-for-adelaide-display').show();
                    $('.rooms-for-adelaide').addClass('active-album-container');
                break;
                case 'The Suburbs':
                    $('.the-suburbs-display').show();
                    $('.the-suburbs').addClass('active-album-container');
                break;
            }
        }
        $('.album-container').click(function(){
            $('.album-display').hide();
            $('.album-container').removeClass('active-album-container');

            if( $(this).hasClass('the-weatherman') ){
                $('.the-weatherman-display').show();
                $('.the-weatherman').addClass('active-album-container');
            }

            if( $(this).hasClass('rooms-for-adelaide') ){
                $('.rooms-for-adelaide-display').show();
                $('.rooms-for-adelaide').addClass('active-album-container');
            }

            if( $(this).hasClass('the-suburbs') ){
                $('.the-suburbs-display').show();
                $('.the-suburbs').addClass('active-album-container');
            }
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: As long as your fetch data is an Array of objects, you can use `Array.prototype.map` and `Array.prototype.filter` to extract the data you need.

Comment: What is your question ? First edit it because the formatting is all over the place. Then please ask a precise question. If you are asking how to do a loop in javascript then you might wanna try google first.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean how to do looping for json data, you can use $.each() method from jQuery, or forEach using native JS.

See:
jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

or

Native JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach

Comment: Personally, I'd use `map`, `filter` and `reduce` if the root object is an array. This makes deeply nested data extraction much easier compared to for each loops .

Comment: I'm not sure how that will help. My sample data won't necessarily reflect the OP's data.